# Php Long polling script consumes 20/20 number of processes on my premium shared hosting. How does it work?

Tags: php, ajax, long-polling

I have my page which make an Ajax call to my PHP script searching for data in the database. When I refresh the page multiple times consecutively, my host's number of processes limit on 20 reached (20/20). Because of that, no more php script can be executed until the processes number gets down in like 3 or more minutes.

What's going on on the host when the page gets called and how to fix it? *Let's say if 30 people (even less) log on my website, my website will crash.*

Here is my script:

```
//Some logic code
session_write_close();

//It was 400
set_time_limit(60);

$genMesaj = false;

do {
    sleep(5);

    //Some codes to search on the database

   //In case some data found
   \session_start();
   session_write_close();

    $genMesaj = //true or false;
} while (!$genMesaj);
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish with the long polling? It appears you're trying to keep the session open and maybe retrieve some data, otherwise this seems kind of inconsequential, I would move your sleep logic to your AJAX call, and relaunch a new request within a promise.

Comment: With the long polling, I'm trying to get new notifications and new messages from the DB. I always close the session after opening it to check for user credentials and write the last notification and message id. I'm gonna set the timeout at the jquery Ajax Call. I don't get that. What do you mean?: **relaunch a new request within a promise. **. And why the shared hosting increments the cpu usage for every request?

Comment: The server is eating CPU cycles to leave the multiple `do while()` loops running, along with all of the other overhead (apache modules, etc). Setting the repeated AJAX calls in a promise is effectively just normal polling, letting your client side script request the data at a set interval, instead of leaving PHP open. See [Promise on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Also, I'm trying to not making too much calls to the server to avoid to much requests. That's why I prefer the long polling.

Comment: I recommend looking into using a single WebSocket server service like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) instead of several generic AJAX requests to a long running PHP script. Another option would be to use [HTTP2 Server push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push) but typically requires more control over the server side configurations, such as with a VPS (virtual private server).

Comment: Before I considered the AJAX long polling, I tried WebSockets like Ratchet and another one (I forgot the name). The problem I read about the websockets is the files limit on Linux which is 1024 [here](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/376). And I don't have access to the server's configuration. I can only change some php.ini configurations. Using VPS or cloud hosting would be a fix for websockets, but I can only pay a shared hosting for that little website. Also, from what I heard Facebook is still using Long polling.

Comment: What would be the long polling best practices to avoid too much requests and too much cpu usage or cycles? considering that my webpage will have to check for new notifications and messages every 5 seconds.

Comment: I just monitored the Facebook website, and the long polling last 50 seconds. So the problem is only the host I am using? the loop and sleep is not really a problem?

Comment: Facebook doesn't use PHP. They use [HHVM](https://hhvm.com/), they also have several server farms with a ton of resources.  You can implement additional servers (cluster) to avoid the 255 concurrent connection limit with Ratchet. Would you have 255+ concurrent users? If so and you are worried about request limits now, I would advise finding a different host without request restrictions. Long-Polling in a shared hosting environment is not advisable, for the simple fact you are using the same server and resources as 100+ other subscribers.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm gonna use websocket for a moment. And I made a mistake about the cpu usage. It was **Number of processes**. I have a max 20 number of processes.

Comment: Ouch, what hosting provider do you use? 20 is very small for a "premium" plan. But yea, the same issue would apply since the request would stay open while the script is running the `do while()` loop. However the fact you are limited to only 20 processes, forces you to use standard polling or WebSockets.

Comment: Thanks for your help. **_This question is off topic._** I'm on ifastnet. What premium hosting do yo know which gives more than 20 number of processes and also wildcard sub-domains (that one is the most important)?

Comment: Also I considered moving my application to AngularJs. Do you thing the same websocket 255 limit is also applied to NodeJS?

Comment: The concurrent limit is specific to [Linux open files limit](https://easyengine.io/tutorials//linux/increase-open-files-limit) and the PHP Ratchet `stream_select` loop, since PHP is compiled with a `FD_SETSIZE` set to 1024 or [256 in windows](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/99230784f5524f5387a8a6760bdaf9aa2eb91545/win32/build/config.w32#L299) by default. You can use a different Ratchet loop that isn't limited or NodeJS sockets, but would still need to address the Linux limits if you plan to exceed the open files limit (different per distro).

Comment: Dreamhost doesn't list any process limits, but may kill a running process if it hits their CPU/Memory limits. HostGator has a limit of 25, GoDaddy has a process limit by cPanel hosting plan; Economy:100, Ultimate:125, Maximum:150 for concurrent connections.  All of them refer to resolving process limits to *The first step is to upgrade to a VPS.* as is generally the preferred hosting option, due to the major limits with shared hosting.

Comment: My website dns is handled by CloudFlare and it seems like Clouflare allows  [HTTP2 Server push](https://blog.cloudflare.com/using-http-2-server-push-with-php/). How does it work using HTTP2 Server push to send data from the DB to the browser without loop?

Comment: It works similarly to WebSockets by having another message consumer running (server) and the client request loading from the webserver with http2 support, It works without the need of running a javascript client-side framework.  I recommend looking into [`Mercure`](https://mercure.rocks) as it is a straight-forward approach to accomplishing what you need. It does require SSL to use.